# Is there such a thing as a "cubic transformation"?

Tags: linear-transformations

I've just learned about "linear transformations" / "linear mapping".

A linear mapping function looks like as follows: $$ f (v, a, b, c, d) = \frac{v - a}{b - a}(d - c) + c $$

Knowing that things like "linear interpolation" and "cubic interpolation" exists, is there such a thing as a "cubic transformation" / "cubic mapping"?

Also, is there such a thing as a "bilinear / bicubic transformation"?

If they exist, what do they look like? And what do they do?

**EDIT**: I'm not a mathematician (I'm a programmer) and I don't know how to represent it properly. So I'm gonna give an example of what I understand by "linear mapping / transformation":

Let's say I have a number that goes from 0 (a) to 50 (b). Let's say 25 (v).

Now I want to map that number to a range that goes from 0 (c) to 100 (d).

If I use the following formula:

(v - a) / (b - a) * (d - c) + c

(25 - 0) / (50 - 0) * (100 - 0) + 0 = **50**

Comment: What you call a linear mapping function  is not linear in its variables. Maybe you can tell us precisely what your b ook says?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I've added an example of what I understand by linear mapping

Comment: OK, it's linear in $v$. I think that we'd call this map something like $f_{a,b,c,d}(v)$. Since cubic interpolation is a thing, there are maps that achieve it. By the way "bilinear transformation" already has a meaning which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Quite generally, a linear transformation is a function $T$ between two $k$-vector spaces $V$ and $W$ that is linear, i.e., such that for any two vectors $v$ and $v'$ in $V$ and any two scalars $a$ and $b$ in $k,$ we have that $T(av + bv') = a T(v) + b T(v').$ Conceptually, linear transformations are a generalization of linear functions $f(x) = mx$ in the Cartesian plane. Indeed, for any four real numbers $a, b, x_1,$ and $x_2,$ we have $$f(ax_1 + bx_2) = m(ax_1 + bx_2) = a(mx_1) + b(mx_2) = a f(x_1) + b f(x_2),$$ hence the function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a linear transformation of the $\mathbb R$-vector space $\mathbb R$ to itself.

One can also consider a bilinear map, i.e., a function of two components that is linear in both components. For instance, the usual dot product of a Euclidean $k$-vector space $V$ (e.g., $\mathbb R^n$) defined by $$\langle x_1, \dots, x_n \rangle \cdot \langle y_1, \dots, y_n \rangle = x_1 y_1 + \cdots + x_n y_n$$ is linear in both components: given an ordered basis $\mathscr B = \{\mathbf v_1, \dots, \mathbf v_n \},$ we may write the vectors $\mathbf x = x_1 \mathbf v_1 + \cdots + x_n \mathbf v_n$ and $\mathbf y = y_1 \mathbf v_1 + \cdots + y_n \mathbf v_n$ as $\mathbf x = \langle x_1, \dots, x_n \rangle$ and $\mathbf y = \langle y_1, \dots, y_n \rangle$ for short. Ultimately, the function $d : V \times V \to k$ defined by $d(\mathbf x, \mathbf y) = \mathbf x \cdot \mathbf y = x_1 y_1 + \cdots + x_n y_n$ is linear in both components since we have that $d(a \mathbf x, \mathbf y) = ax_1 y_1 + \cdots + ax_n y_n = d(\mathbf x, a \mathbf y).$

On the question of a cubic transformation, I am not sure what that would entail. It seems like a natural extension of a linear transformation to require that the function be *cubic* in the sense that for any two vectors $v$ and $v'$ in $V$ and any two scalars $a$ and $b$ in $k,$ we have that $T(av + bv') = a^3 T(v) + b^3 T(v').$ But that seems immediately problematic because the identity function $T(v) = v$ is not a cubic transformation by this definition. In fact, there cannot be a nonzero cubic transformation (as defined) that satisfies $T(av) = av$ for all vectors $v$ and all scalars $a$ since we would have that $T(v) = v$ and $$2 T(v) = T(v) + T(v) = T(v + v) = T(2v) = 2^3 T(v) = 8 T(v).$$

Comment: I've clearly asked something beyond my current knowledge.

Comment: Can I do anything to make things more concrete?

Comment: Don't worry about it, I asked it by pure curiosity.